# How to pass data from firebase app to google map in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, url

I want to send or pass some data from Firebase inside my app into google map
for example I want to send and display some "coordinate" or "itinerary" of a shop

The snippet code below launch google map using url_launcher
I don't know how to do the rest. Any ideas I could use some examples ?

```
    void _openMap() async {
      const url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=52.32,4.917';
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        void initState(){
          super.initState();
          canLaunch( "https://maps.google.com/maps/search");
        }

        await launch(url);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    }
```

The code below is for creating records inside firebase

```
    void createRecord(){
  databaseReference.child("1").set({
    'name': 'Macdonald',
    'location': 'New york'
  });
  databaseReference.child("2").set({
    'name': 'burger king',
    'location': 'Mexico'
  });
}
```

Edit : There is multiple shop with different location (document id)
ex : macdonald, burger king...etc

[Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuiy9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is in Firebase collection then you have to just fetch the coordinates from your Firestore collection and pass it to the above URL. now fetching the coordinates from your collection can be done by below code
first you will fetch all documents and then you will get the field of each document

```
final QuerySnapshot result =
          await Firestore.instance.collection('YOUR COLLECTION Name').getDocuments();
final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;

documents.forEach((data) {
 var cordinates = doc.data['coordinates'];
});
```

Comment: Thank you but I believe this will only work for a single coordinates ?, I have multiple  shop with different coordinates so the location will depend on user choice

Comment: Could you tell me the type of collection you have in your firebase so that I can understand better ?

Comment: Offers > Document ID > field>shop name, location so  the document id change need to attribute it again to another shop

Comment: please make your response more specific because currently its not understood if your field is a list of shops which have location as a parameter or you have single shop inside each document and if you have single document or list of document whose ids are known to you?

Comment: yes its a single shop inside each document, each document have their own shop with their own location, whos ids are known to me

Comment: I have updated the answer if you have list of documents in collection and you want to fetch all the shops associated with each documents