# Returning 0 records from firebase database in my flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have built a flutter app with firebase. I want to fetch all the users which were inserted during the signup process. However, even though there is a record (document) in the 'users' collection, it always passes 0 records. Can anybody help me to solve the issue?

pubspec.yaml

```
    dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.4.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.7
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^3.5.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  get: ^4.3.8
  provider: ^5.0.0
  stacked: ^2.2.3
  stacked_services: ^0.8.13
```

In firestore service class:

```
class FirestoreService extends GetxController {
  final CollectionReference _usersCollectionReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');      

Stream<CustomUser> user = _usersCollectionReference
            .doc('HBCN4rs5gt5nDp1SP8FM')
            .snapshots()
            .map<CustomUser>((document) => CustomUser.fromMap(document));
```

In auth_service class,

```
String? fn;
   _firestoreService.getUser().forEach((element) {
   
   fn = element.fullName;
  print('============full name 1 =============$fn');
  });
  print('============full name 2 =============$fn');
```

Output :

```
============full name 2 =============null
============full name 1 =============John
```

I changed the code as above and now I am able to fetch the record within forEach() but how do I return that value?

Comment: I haven't really looked into your code since it's a while with Firestore. However, if everything looks fine an explanation can be that you have set-up the app a while ago and that the security rules of Firestore now prohibit accessing the data. So if you have done this a few weeks ago, have a look in Firestore > security rules

Comment: Hi, the security rules could be the root of the problem so I also recommend you to check that, and looking around I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196563/how-to-pass-data-from-firebase-app-to-google-map-in-flutter) post that could help you with your issue

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2051, 8, 8);
    }
  }
}

The rule is as above, but still, returns 0 rows. However, I am able to insert records into the firestor db table.

Comment: I changed the codes as above and was able to fetch records. But still, I cannot assign the CustomUser value to a variable outside the forEach()